# Javascript does not insert value on django's formset hidden input field

Tags: javascript, django, formset

I'm attempting to pass a value on a hidden input field in a formset. However when I hit submit I get nothing back: 'form-0-my-field': ['']. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Here's my form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={
        'class': 'my_field'}))
```

formset:

```
MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm, max_num=5)
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = MyFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            print(formset.cleaned_data)
    else:
        formset = MyFormSet()

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', ctx={'formset': formset})
```

And finally my template with a script in the end to target my_field:

```
{% for form in formset.forms %}
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
            {% if forloop.first %}
              {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
              {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
            {{ field }}
          </td>
        {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("my_field").value = "some str";
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("my_field").value);
</script>
```

Comment: What does your alert give?

Comment: I get back: some str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes can match multiple elements. So `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, ie an array of objects (note the `s` in the method name).

To assign a value you need to reference the item within the collection:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my_field")[0].value = "some str";
```

However preferably you would do this via IDs rather than classes.

Comment: It worked! And I agree, a would rather target it by ID. However, how would I target those elements in different collections? For example if I have 3 forms from the same formset, how would I target "my_field" on all of them by ID?